# SSIS write to file options

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

SSIS question, moderate complexity.  I've built a package that reads from a text file that's in the following format:

```
[Section1]
value1
value2

[Section2]
value1
value2
```

The package reads the data into a SQL Server table and then performs some data manipulation.  Now I need to write that manipulated data out to a text file.  I'm trying using a file connection manager but it's a little tricky since the data is only going into one column.  I can script it out which requires a lot more code and I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.  Can someone tell me at least if I'm barking up the wrong tree trying to do it with the file connection object, or if it's even possible with a single column file?

Comment: A sample of what you're attempting to do might make things more clear, especially since SSIS is so persnickety about its data types. What sort of data volumes are you dealing with?

Comment: So you want non-delimited (single column from table) data into delimited format(multiple header), right?

Comment: billinkc, not sure what kind of sample to provide.  The text that I included is pretty much the format I need.  It's only about 50 rows of data, it's just getting it from table to single column format that's got me stumped.